# I tried to adjust datapoint using index and match and applied it to specified group in dataset in R

Tags: r, dplyr, match

i have one dataset recording infection status in chicken. The first column in the groups of chicken which are I and S. the remaining column is the status (0,1) in each sampling time. i need to adjust the information in the I group in which i want to replace the last 0 before the first 1 with 0.5.
i tried it on a vector using index and match

```
v= c(0,0,1,0,1,1,1) 
v[[match(1,v) -1]] = 0.5
```

but i am struggling to apply this to the dataset
I wrote a simplify version of the dataframe here

```
dftry <- data.frame("Role" = c("I", "I", "S", "S", "S", "I"),
                  "T1" = c(0,0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
                  "T2" = c(0,0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
                  "T3"= c(0,0, 1, 0, 1, 1),
                  "T4"= c(1,1,1, 1, 1, 1))**
```

and the desired output should look like this

```
dftry <- data.frame("Role" = c("I", "I", "S", "S", "S", "I"),
                  "T1" = c(0,0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
                  "T2" = c(0,0, 0, 0, 0, 0.5),
                  "T3"= c(0.5,0.5, 1, 0, 1, 1),
                  "T4"= c(1,1,1, 1, 1, 1))
```

I've tried using mutate and innerjoin but it does not seem to work. please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach. You can add row numbers to consider each row indendently. Using `pivot_longer` you can put your data into long format, and then look for transitions from 0 to 1 over time (from T1 to T4) for those with `Role` of "I". The data can be left in this way for further manipulation or analysis, or converted back to wide form as below. Note that this solution considers the transition from one state to another (infection status of 0 to 1) - not necessarily looking at if this involves the "first" status of 1 for a given `Role`.

```
library(tidyverse)

dftry %>%
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -c(Role, rn)) %>%
  group_by(rn) %>%
  mutate(value = ifelse(
    Role == "I" & value == 0 & lead(value) == 1, .5, value
  )) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = c(Role, rn))
```

**Output**

```
  Role     rn    T1    T2    T3    T4
  <chr> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 I         1     0   0     0.5     1
2 I         2     0   0     0.5     1
3 S         3     0   0     1       1
4 S         4     0   0     0       1
5 S         5     0   0     1       1
6 I         6     0   0.5   1       1
```